# Minecraft alpha 1.2.6 lags when loading new chunks. Anyway to tone down the lag?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Recently I've noticed that when I'm loading new chunks in minecraft alpha 1.2.6, it lags. Since this is an **old** version, there might not be a way to combat this, but if there is, how can I tone down the lag? I have 4G RAM and the latest version of Java. My memory usage is at about **20-25%**. Also, I normally get about 60FPS in **small window mode**. (I just like small window better.)

Comment: I'm pretty sure chunk loading is CPU intensive, not ram intensive

Comment: @Ender I'm still going to include it if does involve anything.

Comment: Could you go in-game and press the f3 button? In the top right it should say the memory usage. Could you add that result into your question?

Comment: @Geertsma Updated my question.

Comment: Why are you using such an out-dated edition of Minecraft?!

Comment: @shanodin because I just love the old versions of minecraft, back when it still had it's magic....

Answer (score 1):

> How can I tone down the lag?

You can do the classic "allocate more RAM" mixed with a NORMAL or SHORT render distance. That way the game will load a small number of chunks at the time.

Just set `-Xmx` to the maximum RAM that you want to allocate for the game. As an example:

```
-Xmx512M # 512MB
-Xmx2G # 2GB
```

[image: Launch Parameters]

As far as I know, there is no OptiFine version available for Alphas, Betas or Snapshots.

> Since this is an old version...

Yep, I did some testing with Alpha 1.2.6, Beta 1.5 and Release 1.12.2 and even my "light gaming capable" PC struggled to keep up. Looks like this version is not optimized for recent PCs.

This is my benchmark of the Alpha 1.2.6 (`old_alpha a1.2.6`):

```
Average framerate  :   70.1 FPS
Minimum framerate  :   19.7 FPS
Maximum framerate  :  122.9 FPS
1% low framerate   :    4.1 FPS
0.1% low framerate :    3.0 FPS
```

Just in case, a benchmark of the Beta 1.5 (`old_beta b1.5`):

```
Average framerate  :   81.2 FPS
Minimum framerate  :   39.6 FPS
Maximum framerate  :  157.7 FPS
1% low framerate   :   15.1 FPS
0.1% low framerate :   5.6 FPS
```

And a more recent game version, Release 1.12.2

```
Average framerate  :  126.5 FPS
Minimum framerate  :   43.8 FPS
Maximum framerate  :  222.9 FPS
1% low framerate   :   27.9 FPS
0.1% low framerate :   16.2 FPS
```

All of them used the same world and graphics settings (medium render distance and fast graphics preset) plus none of them were modified. The resolution used was 1366x768.

Answer (score 1):

Lowering the render distance to 10 and capping max frame rate at 60 keeps most lag away for me. And I have an old ass Mac.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue, what worked for me was getting the Technic launcher and installing the old days modpack. It works fine in fullscreen mode and I played for about 2 hours with no lag at 120fps on a 2014 Mac Mini (8gb RAM).